# Changing password of an account through web3

Tags: web3js, password

Can we change the password of an existing account through web3.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't update the password using web3.js check the documentation https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/e4eb9606aa0aa10fd3eeb0a5e5d67c4fff43e814/lib/web3/methods/personal.js
there is no function for updating your password.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum), it's also a JavaScript tool.
When you modify the password of a wallet file, the key pair doesn't change.

```
 var params = {
        keyBytes: 32,
        ivBytes: 16
    };

    var options = {
        kdf: "scrypt",
        cipher: "aes-128-ctr",
        kdfparams: {
            n: (1 << 4),
            dklen: 32,
            p: 1,
            r: 8,
            prf: "hmac-sha256"
        }
    };

var dk = keythereum.create(params);
dk.privateKey = "";//privateKey that recoveried by keythereum.
var keyObject = keythereum.dump(newPassword, dk.privateKey, dk.salt, dk.iv, options);
var obj = JSON.stringify(keyObject);
return obj;
```